# Problem with Docker on Windows [version `GLIBC_2.32' not found] [version `GLIBC_2.34' not found]

Tags: docker, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am following a beginners tutorial for installing Docker on Windows using WSL2.

It's one of the first tutorials/lectures here in this course.

https://www.udemy.com/course/docker-and-kubernetes-the-complete-guide/

I did everything as told so far. To verify that my docker setup is OK,
at the end the tutorial is telling me to just run `docker` inside my
default WSL Linux Distro (which is Ubuntu, that's how it came).

So I ran `docker` but I got this error.

```
/mnt/wsl/docker-desktop/cli-tools/usr/bin/com.docker.cli: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.32' not found (required by /mnt/wsl/docker-desktop/cli-tools/usr/bin/com.docker.cli)

/mnt/wsl/docker-desktop/cli-tools/usr/bin/com.docker.cli: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.34' not found (required by /mnt/wsl/docker-desktop/cli-tools/usr/bin/com.docker.cli)
```

Trying to fix the error I upgraded all Linux packages which were upgradable.
Still no luck. Seems it's saying it needs higher version of GLIBC than mine.
But also, I see no way to further upgrade my GLIBC version. Right?

What should I do to fix this issue?

```
root@LAPTOP1:/mnt/c/Users/user01# docker
/mnt/wsl/docker-desktop/cli-tools/usr/bin/com.docker.cli: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.32' not found (required by /mnt/wsl/docker-desktop/cli-tools/usr/bin/com.docker.cli)
/mnt/wsl/docker-desktop/cli-tools/usr/bin/com.docker.cli: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.34' not found (required by /mnt/wsl/docker-desktop/cli-tools/usr/bin/com.docker.cli)
root@LAPTOP1:/mnt/c/Users/user01# ldd --version
ldd (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.31-0ubuntu9.14) 2.31
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
Written by Roland McGrath and Ulrich Drepper.
root@LAPTOP1:/mnt/c/Users/user01# apt-cache policy libc6
libc6:
  Installed: 2.31-0ubuntu9.14
  Candidate: 2.31-0ubuntu9.14
  Version table:
 *** 2.31-0ubuntu9.14 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.31-0ubuntu9 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
root@LAPTOP1:/mnt/c/Users/user01# apt-get install libc6
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
libc6 is already the newest version (2.31-0ubuntu9.14).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 11 not upgraded.
root@LAPTOP1:/mnt/c/Users/user01#
```

These are my distros.

```
PS C:\Users\user01> wsl --list --verbose
  NAME                   STATE           VERSION
* Ubuntu                 Running         2
  docker-desktop         Running         2
  docker-desktop-data    Running         2
```

And this is my WSL Ubuntu version.

```
root@LAPTOP1:/mnt/c/Users/user01# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I upgraded my Ubuntu version by following the instructions given here.

https://askubuntu.com/a/1428481

Now my version is `22.04.3 LTS`.

```
root@LAPTOP1:/mnt/c/Users/user01# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy
root@LAPTOP1:/mnt/c/Users/user01#
```

And it seems that solved my problem. Now I am not getting that GLIBC error when I run `docker` from within the Ubuntu command prompt.

I don't know why by default WSL2 doesn't install directly this version `22.04.3 LTS`. Not sure what's the point of having to upgrade it manually later on.

Comment: Picking a different release would just be choosing to be ABI-incompatible with a different set of software. It fixes compatibilty with _your_ particular tool, but it's not a universal "everything always works" button. (In general, Linux is an ecosystem where people are assumed to have compilers, and to be able to recompile software to be binary-compatible with their local distro -- unlike Windows where everything is distributed as binaries so ABI compatibility, rather than source compatibility, is critical).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Yes, OK... but remember my context. I am following a simple tutorial for getting Docker to run on Windows/WSL. With the old version 20.04.6 it does not run OK. With the new version 22.04.3 it seems to run OK. So for my case, it seems I need the newer version of Ubuntu.

Comment: One other bit of context: 20.04 is a LTS release, meaning it's scheduled for _long-term support_; it's still getting regular security patches until 2025, and customers paying for extended support will keep getting it until after 2030 -- so it's a very reasonable choice to target for any VM image or installer one doesn't want to be constantly revving; this means that any package of Docker that Canonical built for Ubuntu 20.04 is _likewise_ getting security updates through 2025; that your tutorial is telling you to use a Docker package that isn't the Canonical one is a problem w/ that tutorial.

Comment: That is to say: _Docker itself_ can run just fine on Ubuntu 20.04; it's specifically _the copy of Docker that your tutorial is telling you to install_ that's a problem.

Comment: (I suspect that the effort to use Docker Desktop instead of OSS Docker is _why_ the tutorial is telling you not to use Ubuntu's supported build, but that's a bad idea -- among other things, commercial support agreements for Docker are crazy expensive, so it makes good sense to learn the tools that you can use even if your company isn't paying for commercial licenses for the free-for-personal-use-only subset -- and I advise against any tutorial that would send you down that path)

Answer (score 1):

This is issue that should be fixed in next patch release (this week or month) - guessing 4.26.1 or similar.
Check some details here: https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/13824.

As another workaround than upgrading WSL2 distro to 22.04 you can try to use docker commands from PowerShell. Storage of images and containers is shared so later on you should be able to continue your work from WSL2

Answer (score -1):

just put in terminal:

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```